# Is there any map data structure that allows fast merging?

Tags: data-structures, merge, binary-tree, big-o

Are there any map data structures that have at least `O(log n)` insertion, deletion, access, and merging?

Most [self-balancing binary trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) such as [AVL trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) and [red-black trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree) have most of these properties, but I believe they have `O(n log n)` merging. Are there any data structures that have faster merging?

Edit: I have looked around, and I can't find anything like this. If there is no such data structure, I would love some insight into why this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at splay trees.  You'll probably end up paying the merging cost along the way, but you should be able to inject another tree in and put the cost off until later.

Comment: That looks cool, I might use it... I just don't like the idea of destructive  reads.

Comment: @Zifre: The reads really aren't destructive. If anything they generally *improve* the structure of the tree -- and they do not change its external representation.

Comment: The constant factor on splay trees is pretty bad. If you merge infrequently enough, you may come out ahead with an "inferior" worst-case running time for merges.

Comment: Also, the improvement that Captain Segfault is referring to is known as the Dynamic Optimality conjecture, of which some special cases have been established. It states in essence that for any access sequence, a splay tree uses at most O(1) times as many operations as any other binary tree. This has many consequences, for example: if some items are accessed very frequently, then they become cheaper than O(log n) to access.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need a tree for arbitrary key types that only have a comparison defined, or would it be OK if it only works with types that have a fixed-size binary representation (int, long, float, double, ...)? If the latter is the case, then a binary radix tree is a data structure that has very efficient merging (O(1) if you are lucky, O(N) worst case).

See [Fast Mergeable Integer Maps](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.37.5452) by Chris Okasaki and Andrew Gill for details of the data structure.

The Scala Collections Library contains an implementation for [ints](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.IntMap) and [longs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.LongMap). All other java primitive types can be translated to either ints or longs, e.g. by using java.lang.Double.doubleToLongBits for Double.